# string escape processing in flex

Tags: string, flex-lexer, lexer

For a class on compilers I am building a lexer. I have completed the assignment, but am left with one point that I am not fully satisfied with.

The language supports string literals with escape sequences, where a string literal is defined as a sequence of characters enclosed by double quotes (`"`) and an escape sequence starts with a backslash (`\`). The lexer is supposed to produce a token for string literals with the escape sequences already processed (such as replacing `\n` with a newline character and `\t` with a tab).

My question is, is it possible to recognize such string literals (and process the escape sequences contained in them) *without copying the parts matched so far to a temporary buffer*? And if it is possible, how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to recognize the literals without use of a temporary buffer, but it is not possible to process them, for the simple reason that `flex` owns the input buffer and the string pointed to by `yytext` (which happens to be a pointer into the input buffer, but that isn't guaranteed either).

But it doesn't really matter. As you will soon discover, in the normal usage of the lexer in combination with `yacc`/`bison`, you need to copy any lexical string into a temporary buffer anyway, because `yacc`/`bison` needs to read one token ahead in the input, and -- as above -- `lex`/`flex` doesn't guarantee to preserve the string pointed to by `yytext` once it starts recognizing the next token. (That's not theoretical: it really doesn't preserve the string's value, and "Why do my strings keep changing?" is probably the most frequently asked yacc/lex question (and according to the bison manual, the most common invalid bug report).

There are workarounds -- including writing your own lexer -- but they require an awful lot of bookkeeping and for very little value, because copying a token string is actually not a very expensive operation. So my advice is: copy your strings and stop worrying. :)